# Ejecutar instrucción SQL dependiendo del resultado de la condición

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Descripción del problema:**

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado que recibe como parámetro un XML que representa información de la tabla *Personas* de la base de datos.

Lo que pretendo realizar con este procedimiento almacenado es:

- Evaluar si la Persona *recibida en el XML* **existe** en la tabla *Personas* de la base de datos.
- Si existe, actualizar determinadas columnas de la tabla Personas con la información que contiene el XML de Personas.
- De lo contrario *(es decir, **si no existe**)*, insertar un nuevo registro en la tabla *Personas*.

---

**Descripción de las tablas involucradas:**

*Personas:* Tabla SQL que administra la información de las personas.

```
+-------------------+--------+
| Identificacion    | Nombre |
+-------------------+--------+
| 1011457           | Alex   |
+-------------------+--------+
| 1548915           | Juan   |
+-------------------+--------+
| 6215478           | Rosa   |
+-------------------+--------+
| 1324785           | Andrea |
+-------------------+--------+
| 2157984           | Felipe |
+-------------------+--------+
```

@XML_Personas: Parámetro del procedimiento almacenado que posee la siguiente estructura:

** En este caso, la información del XML y de la base de datos son la misma. Es solo un ejemplo.*

```
DECLARE @XML_Personas XML
SET @XML_Personas = '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
                    <NewDataSet>
                      <Personas>
                        <Identificacion>1011457</Identificacion>
                        <Nombre>Alex</Nombre>
                      </Personas>
                      <Personas>
                        <Identificacion>1548915</Identificacion>
                        <Nombre>Juan</Nombre>
                      </Personas>
                      <Personas>
                        <Identificacion>6215478</Identificacion>
                        <Nombre>Rosa</Nombre>
                      </Personas>
                      <Personas>
                        <Identificacion>1324785</Identificacion>
                        <Nombre>Andrea</Nombre>
                      </Personas>
                      <Personas>
                        <Identificacion>2157984</Identificacion>
                        <Nombre>Felipe</Nombre>
                      </Personas>
                    </NewDataSet>'
```

De esta manera convierto el XML en una tabla *temporal*:

```
-- Tabla temporal para traducir el XML.
DECLARE @tblPersonas AS TABLE 
(
    Identificacion INT,
    Nombre VARCHAR(50)
)

-- Obtener Valores del XML.
INSERT INTO @tblPersonas
SELECT  Tbl.Col.value('Identificacion[1]', 'INT'),
        Tbl.Col.value('Nombre[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
FROM    @XML_Personas.nodes('//Personas') Tbl(Col)
```

---

He intentado hasta el momento:

*Usando Common Table Expressions (CTE), separar la sub-consulta que me lista las Identificaciones y la cantidad de identificaciones que existen según el XML.*

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT personaSQL.Identificacion, ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(personaSQL.Identificacion)
                                      FROM @tblPersonas AS XMLpersona
                                      WHERE XMLpersona.Identificacion = personaSQL.Identificacion), 0) AS [CantidadDatos]
    FROM Personas AS personaSQL
    GROUP BY personaSQL.Identificacion
)
SELECT (CASE WHEN CTE.CantidadDatos = 1 THEN (EXEC SP_UPDATE_PERSONA '', '', '', '') AS 'Actualizado' 
                                       ELSE (EXEC SP_INSERT:PERSONA '', '', '', '') AS 'Nuevo' END) AS 'Resultado'
```

*Intenté además* reemplazar los llamados a los procedimientos almacenados `SP_UPDATE_PERSONA` y `SP_INSERT_PERSONA` respectivamente por las instrucciones `UPDATE` e `INSERT`, pero obtengo estos errores:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 70
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UPDATE'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 72
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 74
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Estos errores me dicen que no me permiten este tipo de acciones en la sentencia `SELECT`.

Estoy buscando una manera que me permita en un procedimiento almacenado evaluar cada caso y así realizar la inserción o actualización de las personas.

Comment: Por favor actualiza tu ejemplo para usar la variable `@PeopleXml`, actualmente no queda claro dónde se está usando

Comment: @Lamak hecho, además he agregado la forma que uso para convertir el XML en una tabla temporal. Gracias por tu interés.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no puedes ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado dentro de un `select` para cada fila (y aún si se pudiera, no sería lo recomendable, porque lo estarías ejecutando una vez por fila, en vez de ejecutarlo sólo una vez con todas las filas necesarias).

Lo que tienes que hacer es simplemente un `UPDATE` y un `INSERT`:

```
-- Actualización de la información existente
UPDATE A
SET A.Nombre = B.Nombre,
    A.OtraColumna = B.OtraColumna -- acá puedes listar las columnas que quieres actualizar
FROM dbo.Personas A
INNER JOIN @tblPersonas B
    ON A.Identificacion = B.Identificacion;

-- Inserción de datos que no existían
INSERT INTO dbo.Personas(Identificacion, Nombre, OtraColumna) 
SELECT Identificacion, Nombre, OtraColumna
FROM @tblPersonas A
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Personas
                 WHERE Identificacion = A.Identificacion);
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opción puede ser utilizar la función MERGE de SQL Server, la cual permite realizar inserciones, actualizaciones y eliminaciones en una sola instrucción, asumiendo que la tabla de destino se llama `dbo.Personas`, la funcionalidad puede quedar así:

```
DECLARE @XML_Personas XML
SET @XML_Personas = '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
                    <NewDataSet>
                      <Personas>
                        <Identificacion>1011457</Identificacion>
                        <Nombre>Alex</Nombre>
                      </Personas>
                      <Personas>
                        <Identificacion>1548915</Identificacion>
                        <Nombre>Juan</Nombre>
                      </Personas>
                      <Personas>
                        <Identificacion>6215478</Identificacion>
                        <Nombre>Rosa</Nombre>
                      </Personas>
                      <Personas>
                        <Identificacion>1324785</Identificacion>
                        <Nombre>Andrea</Nombre>
                      </Personas>
                      <Personas>
                        <Identificacion>2157984</Identificacion>
                        <Nombre>Felipe</Nombre>
                      </Personas>
                    </NewDataSet>'

-- Tabla temporal para traducir el XML.
DECLARE @tblPersonas AS TABLE 
(
    Identificacion INT,
    Nombre VARCHAR(50)
)

-- Obtener Valores del XML.
INSERT INTO @tblPersonas
SELECT  Tbl.Col.value('Identificacion[1]', 'INT'),
        Tbl.Col.value('Nombre[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
FROM    @XML_Personas.nodes('//Personas') Tbl(Col)

--Se utiliza la función MERGE para realizar el proceso de inserción y actualización.
MERGE dbo.Personas AS target
USING 
(
    SELECT  
        [Identificacion]
        ,[Nombre]                   
    FROM 
        @tblPersonas        
) AS source ([Identificacion],[Nombre])
ON (target.Identificacion = source.Identificacion)          
WHEN MATCHED THEN   
    UPDATE
    SET [Nombre] = source.Nombre                    
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY target THEN 
    INSERT ([Identificacion], [Nombre])
    VALUES (source.Identificacion, source.Nombre)                   
;
```

Comment: Recomiendo precaución al usar `MERGE`, ya que tiene muchos bugs conocidos que quedaron en estado "no se arreglarán" por el equipo de Microsoft. [Acá dejo un link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) explicando alguno de los problemas relacionados a `MERGE`

Comment: @Lamak, gracias por la información, realmente no conocía estos detalles. De todas maneras he usado esta instrucción en varios proyectos y no he tenido ningun problema. Le recomiendo a Mauricio que igualmente ensaye la solución, si le sirve creo que la puede implementar pero revisa el apunte que indica Lamak.